# In android ,how to set layout_marginRight in code

Tags: android, layout, margin

below is a textview layout , and I hope to modify layout_marginRight to zero in code.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/status1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/keyguard_lockscreen_status_line_font_right_margin"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="@dimen/keyguard_lockscreen_status_line_font_size"
                android:drawablePadding="4dip"
 />
```

when I copy aqif code  to my code as below,   phone halt at power on animation.

```
private void updateStatus1() {
        if (mStatus1View != null) {
            MutableInt icon = new MutableInt(0);
            CharSequence string = getPriorityTextMessage(icon);
            mStatus1View.setText(string);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mStatus1View.getLayoutParams();
            params.rightMargin = 0;
            mStatus1View.setLayoutParams(params);

            mStatus1View.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon.value, 0, 0, 0);
            mStatus1View.setVisibility(mShowingStatus ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: you said, "phone halt at power on animation."

What your application is, how your code gets executed at the start of phone?

Answer (score 10):

you can do it this way.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.rightMargin = 30;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

to set Values in `dp` you can do it like this.

```
params.rightMargin = (int) (30f * this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

and the type of params depends upon its parent, if your view parent is `LinearLayout` the your params must be of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` type, and in case of `RelativeLayout`, your params must be of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` type.

regards,
Aqif Hamid

Answer (score 0):

try as by using [ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.rightMargin](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html):

```
TextView extView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tv.getLayoutParams();
//params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0); //setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
params.rightMargin=0; 
tv.setLayoutParams(params);
```